# What is this black shelled insect found in Western Arkansas?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

This bug was running around my driveway last night. It was *very* fast and wouldn't hold still - this is about the clearest shot that I got of it. As far as I could tell, there were no legs behind that 3rd segment - it was just dragging those.

I've never seen this, or anything like this in Arkansas. What is it?

[image: Weird black bug]

Comment: Approximate size?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like the larvae of a carrion or burrowing beetle (i.e. some beetle species of the family *Silphidae*). Not sure on the species yet.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silphidae) provides a good introduction to this family of insects.

Here's a picture:
[image]

And another:
[Silphidae larvae](http://www.naturespot.org.uk/species/silphidae-larvae)

Did you see (or more likely *smell*) any dead carcasses around your property?

Comment: That's surely it. We actually have a cat that kills moles, a variety of rodents, and (sadly) birds. I suspect it was after one of those. It's odd, though, because it looks like the adult beetles are fairly large, and I haven't noticed any of them yet.